# What is this buzzing sound playing?

Tags: bleach, music

I heard this on buzz channel which is an anime channel, and now also in bleach. In episode 2 You can hear it at around 14:00 in [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=My-tTlsJD1I&feature=player_detailpage#t=840)

Does this sound have a specific name? or is it some sort of soundtrack?

Answer (score 5):

Are you talking about the [Tōryanse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C5%8Dryanse)? A traditional children's song that's commonly used at street crossings to indicate that it's free to cross the street.